# Geometry Nodes: Moving particles inside of an object

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

I'm trying to figure out a way to create moving particles inside of an object with geometry nodes. Currently I have noise texture which animates the "particles", but I can't figure out how to make them stay inside of an object.

I assume I need to add an additional object in the scene or replace the grid with an ico sphere. And use their attributes to calculate the difference with the offset noise is connected to. But how do I do this?

[image: This is where I am at now:]

Comment: maybe - instead of asking for a special technique - you should also tell us your "big" end goal what you are really trying to achieve. Because often we think in a total wrong or laborious direction what could be solved much easier...just e.g. if you wanna animate lottery balls - rigid body animation would be much easier than geometry nodes...

Comment: Oh, I don't really have a "big end goal". I'm asking because of the technique. I'm trying to learn so that I could use it in the future, and maybe combine this with other things to create something cool looking. Like you said lottery balls, snow globe, vfx glowing orbs.... Maybe it is easier to think if I say in this case I would like to create an glowing orb with particles inside of it.